# How to Fetch one row each from single column name with different column value from WordPress database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I needed to fetch one row each from a single Column name with different column values.
Here is what I am trying to do...

```
$pm = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_prematch` WHERE league_id IN(3,6) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() < (timer) ORDER BY timer limit 2");

foreach ($pm as $event) {
    //output
}
```

This one the column name is league_id. I have repetitive league_id of both 3 and 6 with many rows.

What I am trying to get is one row each from two different league_id. The above code fetch both the two rows from single league_id based on timer order.

Suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: I think need to use window functions like ROW_NUMBER()/DENSE_RANK() (MySQL 8.0+) or simulate it with MySQL's user variables..  Pretty sure there is a duplication on this website.. But it is hard to answer without table structures/example data and expected results you i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If the league id is very few we can simply use use union all ... SELECT * FROM `wp_prematch` WHERE league_id =3 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() < (timer) ORDER BY timer limit 1 union all SELECT * FROM `wp_prematch` WHERE league_id =6 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() < (timer) ORDER BY timer limit 1;

Comment: @jithingiri is still the same first fetching the rows of first league_id

Comment: Please read this then [edit] your question.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/